# eclipse che docker desktop installation is unable to pull images from private docker registry

Tags: docker, eclipse-che

Aim is to have a default workspace created for each new user.

User will visit the link https://che-eclipse-che.192.168.0.1.nip.io/#https://github.com/test/eclipse-che
It has the devfile to create the workspace.

First user registration will happen via keycloak and then the workspace will be created. This means a new kubernetes namespace will also be created for the user.

The problem is that I need to use an image from a private docker registry but I'm unable to specify the authentication credentials in the devfile. Is there any way to achieve this?

Can not use kubernetes secret because secrets are confined to a namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Withing Che, you can't configure your credentials to be used for every user.
Each is supposed to configure their credentials, if they need access private docker repos. Check https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/che-7/end-user-guide/using-private-container-registries/

What I can propose to look into:

- configure nodes to pull private image https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#configuring-nodes-to-authenticate-to-a-private-registry;
- push your images to cluster internal docker registry;